# C# - Should APIs ever have the "async" modifier on them?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've been searching and searching and am unable to find ANY method in the .NET Library and Framework that has the "async" modifier on it and is considered an API.

I've seen it being used in their code, but it is not being "exposed".

It then brings me to another question, should we EVER expose "async API methods", or just expose APIs as Task. I think the answer is latter, but maybe someone can show me a case where it isn't.

I also don't remember where I read this, but I'm sure I read this somewhere.

Comment: Why would you not expose the `async` though?

Comment: In other words; An API call that provides a promise.  This seems like a very viable option, but I've never thought about it until now.  Interesting I can't wait to hear what other people think.

Comment: So what is the difference between "async method" and "method that returns the Task"?

Comment: The problem is if I expose a method as async, then synchronous methods need to do a Task.Run( () => ... ) ... but without it, the caller has to decide what to do.

Comment: @halivingston - I'm not sure what you're thinking about with that comment, but it's not true. A method returning a running `Task` is a method returning a running `Task`, whether or not it's decorated with `async`. The *caller* has exactly the same options/responsibilities either way. As I've indicated in my answer, `async` is about how the method is *implemented*, and has no observable impact on callers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` is an *implementation* detail.

The *signature* of the method is just a method that returns `Task` or `Task<T>`.

All that `async` does is to change what variation of C# you can write *within* the method. It's completely invisible to calling code.

This is why you're not *allowed* to declare `async` on interface members - it being an implementation detail, and interfaces not having implementations, it doesn't make sense.

So, your decision to make in re: APIs is what you want your methods to return. If it's `Task` or `Task<T>`, it's *entirely your decision* about whether to implement that method `async` or not, and you're free to change that decision later (adding `async` later doesn't change the method signature - it's not a breaking change)

---

For other API considerations, you may wish to consult a pair of articles by Stephen Toub entitled [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) and [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). The short answer to both is no.

Answer (score 2):

The .Net Framework exposes methods that are declared with `async`. If they can, I say you can too.

But that said: If memory serves, a method declared with `async` isn't any different than a method that returns a `Task<>`. I think that the C# compiler takes the `async` method and, in effect, modifies it, and compiles it the same as if it was declared as returning `Task<>`.

Examples of the .Net Framework having a *public* method on a *public* class declared async:

- [System.IO.TextReader.ReadToEndAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#359ce127832cf481)

  - Note that internal child class System.IO.TextReader.SyncTextReader overrides ReadToEndAsync. The base class uses keyword `async`, this class overrides that with [`Task<String>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#8b1f7ff53924c817), emphasizing that they are equivalent.
- class [System.Xml.XmlReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#086471e5cca0825f)

  - [ReadContentAsObjectAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#fd1d877396b91cbb)
  - [ReadContentAsStringAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#8eb52d2950b41600)
  - [ReadContentAsAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#4bbace8d0846cab8)
  - [ReadElementContentAsObjectAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#d1a947000b0da3a5)
  - [ReadElementContentAsStringAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#4c750bee178fbe59)
  - [ReadElementContentAsAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#a5dd2e4f180635f6)
  - [MoveToContentAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#43b05c1afc99c0d3)
  - [ReadInnerXmlAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#da9693a0bb5ca210)
  - [ReadOuterXmlAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlReaderAsync.cs.html#e7d5bb2bf56d43af)
  - Many methods on the base class XmlReader are declared with `Task<>`, but subclasses that are internal to the .Net Framework override them with `async`.

    - Example: class [System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlValidatingReaderImplAsync.cs.html#e5785635b8de37cf)
- class [System.Xml.XmlWriter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriterAsync.cs.html#e5032b905808fabc)

  - [WriteQualifiedNameAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriterAsync.cs.html#44e8c15bc86f372c)
  - [WriteAttributesAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriterAsync.cs.html#921eb8a97c3dbdc5)
  - [WriteNodeAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriterAsync.cs.html#e6f0a439e9e21ed5)
  - [WriteElementStringAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriterAsync.cs.html#f15d428cf265016d)
  - Many methods on the base class XmlWriter are declared with `Task<>`, but subclasses that are internal to the .Net Framework override them with `async`.

    - Example: class [System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlUtf8RawTextWriterAsync.cs.html#4d49c49c2e737fec)
- [System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntityAsync()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Xml/System/Xml/XmlUrlResolverAsync.cs.html#04d007b7c485d2a4)

Beyond the public ones, there's many instances where an internal method is declared `async`, and the public method is declared as returning `Task<>`. In general, these are where the public method does some parameter checking, then it calls the internal `async` method and returns the `Task<>`.